# Google Analytics via Iframe in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, google-analytics

I'm having an issue with GA in IE. I'm tracking a goal that starts in my landing page on http://www.mydomain.com. (**www.mydomain.com** --> **wwwGA profile**)

The goal attempts to track a visit from the moment someone sees the landing page until he performs a certain action.

When the user signs up, it is redirected to his admin panel on usersubdomain.mydomain.com (he will use our service from that subdomain). (**user.anotherdomain.com** --> **subGA profile**)

So www.mydomain.com and user.anotherdomain.com have two different profiles.

At some given moment in time, this user may perform an action on his admin panel that's the trigger for finishing the GA goal in wwwGA profile. So I need a way to let the wwwGA profile know this action occurred.

user.anotherdomain.com is always accessed via HTTPS.

What I am currently doing is:

- If the action is performed in the admin panel I set a flag action_performed = 1
- If action_performed == 1:

  1. Show the following iframe `<iframe src="http://www.mydomain.com/track-action-performed" width="1" height="1"></iframe>`
  2. set action_performed = 0

When this iframe is included, it should track the visit on the wwwGA profile (the wwwGA profile is set to complete the goal if the user hits http://www.mydomain.com/track-action-performed).

This works in all browsers except IE.

What I already tried without success

- P3P headers on www.domain.com (this actually worked in making IE accept the iframe
  cookies - at least the ones from www.domain.com) as Google suggests in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#trackingIFrames
- Tried both http:// and https:// as the iframe source.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!